# Workaround for lack of TLS v1.3 support in Apache Commons Net 3.4.0 and Java 8u201

Tags: java

I am using the Apache Commons Net 3.4.0 library to establish an FTPS connection, but I have encountered an issue with the lack of support for TLS v1.3 in the Java 8u201 release.

I know that Oracle releases starting with version 8u261 have support for TLS v1.3, but I am unable to update or replace the JDK distribution.

Is there a workaround or solution to this issue that would allow me to use TLS v1.3? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you update or replace the JDK distribution? That is _the_ solution for this.

Comment: It is a production system, and we can't afford any resulting bugs. I don't think you can update the Java version on existing systems that lightly, can you?

Comment: That has to be the worst reason for sticking to an outdated Java version, especially one that is **years** out of date. You're now confronted with the consequences of that decision, and instead of reconsidering, you're doubling down. Applying a workaround -- if such workaround even exists -- would far more likely result in problems than upgrading to a higher version of the same major version of Java. Java is extensively tested for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

There are no alternatives nor workarounds. The TLS implementation in Java comes with the JDK. You need to upgrade the JDK to one that supports TLS 1.3. For security reasons the latest release of the version you use is recommended.